# How do I encode password with UserPasswordEncoderInterface inside a repository?

Tags: symfony4, php-7.1

In my repository, I would like to do something like:

```
public function generatePassword(Users $user, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
{
    return $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user,$user->getPlainPassword());
}
```

but the function inside a controller expects the second argument. Is there a way to load UserPasswordEncoderInterface automatically or initialize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using [constructor injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html).

You should load your `UserPasswordEncoderInterface` in your repository class and save it globally (in your class). You can use it then without having to declare it in a function parameter.

Something like this:

```
class Repository
{
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function generatePassword(Users $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user,$user->getPlainPassword());
    }
}
```

Also type-hint your service.